# Как сделать, чтобы события срабатывали по удалению атрибута?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="12" onchange = 'ppriceс("1","12");'?><br>
 <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="13" onchange = 'ppriceс("2","13");'?><br>

 <a href="#" class="cdel" >снять отметки></a>

 <span id="sum">0</span>



 function ppriceс(id,val) {

    sum = document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML; 

    id = document.getElementById(id);

    if (id.checked) {

    eprice = (+sum + +val);

    } else {

    eprice = (sum - val);

    }

    $('#sum').html(eprice);

 };

$(".cdel").click(function() {
  $("input:checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
});
```

Вот нужно, чтобы по клику на "снять отметки" выполнялась функция ppriceс с передачей параметров id и name. 
https://jsfiddle.net/u8yj1k9k/

Comment: почему бы не вызывать ф-ю из обработчика клика?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как вычисления производятся на событие `change`, а при удалении атрибута оно не вызывается, нужно вызывать его вручную.

```js
function ppriceс(id, val) {

  sum = document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML;

  id = document.getElementById(id);

  if (id.checked) {

    eprice = (+sum + +val);

  } else {

    eprice = (sum - val);

  }

  $('#sum').html(eprice);

};

$(".cdel").click(function() {
  $("input:checkbox:checked").removeAttr("checked").change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="1" name="12" onchange='ppriceс("1","12");' ?>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="13" onchange='ppriceс("2","13");' ?>
<br>

<a href="#" class="cdel">снять отметки </a>
<br>
<span id="sum">0</span>
```

Comment: + вызов тригера: `.trigger("change");`

Comment: ой точно... Спасибо